# Clicking through to questions from "reputation" tab does not use canonical URL

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, hyperlinks

Take, for example, [the reputation tab of my user profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/89334?tab=reputation). Note that the links to questions do not use the canonical URL because they omit the question title in the URL.

Comment: This seems to me a feature request rather than a bug. Personally this does not affect my experience of the site in any way. If you *really* want to get the canonical URL for some question, you can do so quite easily by clicking the non-canonical link, then scrolling to the top where the question is stated and clicking on the question title.

Answer (score 1):

What difference does it make?

This tag is present in your user page

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/89334/waiwai933">
```

That means you can use whatever form the URL you want, and search engines will know that this form is canon.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical

Comment: Then why do you include the title on every other link on the Stack Exchange site? Because, as I understand, the link is more meaningful that way. I only mentioned canonical because that's the one SE typically uses—I'm familiar with how canonical urls work.